# question based RSA Algorithm

Tags: cryptography

The RSA system was used to encrypt the message M into the cipher-text C = 6. The
public key is given by n = p  q = 187 and e = 107. In the following, we will try to crack
the system and to determine the original message M.

(a) What parameters comprises the public key and what parameters the private key?

(b) What steps are necessary to determine the private key from the public key?

(c) Determine the private key for the given system.

(d) What is the original message M?

How would i solve this?

Comment: Assuming you have a basic knowledge of RSA: What is the first part you cannot solve?

Comment: the last part actually. I have the public key and the private key. But i have no idea how to use it to decrypt it.

Comment: Do you have the private key already? Decryption is basicly $M=C^d \pmod n.$ How do you normally compute the private exponent $d?$

Comment: ok. but C is 6 and d is 23.and from the question, n is 187 How do you calculate something like that?

Comment: No, your $d$ is wrong. You should have $d\times e \equiv 1 \pmod {\varphi(n)}$

Comment: oh.. ok. i'll check that again.

Comment: yeaa. i made a mistake. d = 3. Thanks a lot for the help. but could you tell me what to do if d was a huge number like 23?

Comment: You normally use a fast modular exponentiation (AKA square-and-multiply algorithm),  
see e.g. the Right-to-left binary method at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

(A) The public key is $(n,e)$ and the private key is $d$. We know $ed=1$  $(mod (p-1)(q-1))$.

(B) $c:=m^e (mod (n))$

If you can compute the private key d, you can compute $c^d (mod \, n)$ to get m, since $c^d = (m^e)^d= m^1 (mod \, n)$ since $ed \equiv 1 (mod \,n) $.